# Read ANOTHER new line using fscanf in C

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

Suppose I have a file to read:

```
//it may contain more than 2 lines
12 6
abadafwg
```

And suppose now i have already read the first line like this:

```
char input[999];
while(!feof(fpin))
{
    fscanf(fpin, " %[^\n]", input);
    //do something here with these numbers
    //should do something here to read 2nd line
}
```

Here is my question, how do I read the second line of that file?
Please Help QAQ

Comment: 'fscanf(fpin, " %[^\n]", input)' same but with whitespace

Comment: @PHIfounder its a string

Comment: Have you tried running this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fscanf(fpin, "%[^\n]", input)`, recommend `fgets()` as that prevents buffer overrun.  You can use this for both lines then parse as needed.

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), fpin) == 0) {
  // handle error, EOF
}
int i[2];
int result = sscanf(input,"%d %d", &i[0], &i[1]);
switch (result) {
  case -1: // eof
  case 0: // missing data
  case 1: // missing data
  case 2: // expected
}
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), fpin) == 0) {
  // handle error, EOF
}
// use the 'abadfwg just read
```

Comment: ok...but actually, the file is more than 2 lines and I am not supposed to know how many lines it is containing. I only know that 1st line is 2 numbers, 2nd line is a string, 3rd line 2 numbers, etc. and I need to use those 2 numbers to do something and then use the string, so.....btw, the teacher recommend us to use fscanf...

Comment: Put the 2 reads in a loop to cope with N pairs of lines, watch for result == EOF (-1) to indicate completion of reading the file.  Should you want to use `fscanf()`, try `result = fscanf(fpin, "%d %d", &i[0], &i[1]);` and ``result = fscanf(fpin, " %[^\n]", input);`.  Note the leading spaces consumes whitespace, including any previous un-read `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided will read ALL the lines in the program (one line per iteration of the while loop) and not just the first line. [I tested it just now]